# How do I target the next div when it's not a sibling?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="boxes">
     <div class="box main current">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>

     <div class="box main">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>

     <div class="box main">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>

     <div class="box main">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
    <div class="box sub">
          ... content ...
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to target the next `.main` and add `.next` to it using jquery. I'm trying to following but this doesn't work:

```
var current = $('.main.current');

var next = current.next('.main');
next.addClass('next');
```

[here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYs59/)

Comment: try selecting `$('.boxes .current');`

Comment: this should help you with your selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/AA3ZK/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.current').nextAll('.main').first().addClass('next')
```

[Updated your JSFiddle :)](http://jsfiddle.net/NYs59/2/)
[Example when current is not the first one](http://jsfiddle.net/NYs59/4/)

`next` wasn't working because it only retrieves the *immediate* following sibling, or nothing if the selector doesn't match.

Comment: The problem with using `siblings()` is that even *prior* siblings will be matched. If `.current` is not the first element, `.next` might be erroneously identified as coming *before* `.current`: http://jsfiddle.net/NYs59/3/

Comment: You are absolutely right, I made an example to test it, and updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using jQuery's [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/).

`next()` only returns the *immediate sibling*, while `nextAll()` returns *all subsequent siblings*.

Below, I'm using `.eq(0)` to return the first element in the set matched by `nextAll()`:

```js
var $current = $('.main.current');
var $next = $current.nextAll('.main').eq(0);
$next.addClass('next');
```

Or as a [one-liner](http://jsfiddle.net/5dF67/2/), for brevity:

```
$('.main.current').nextAll('.main').eq(0).addClass('next');
```

---

Try it with the snippet below:

```js
var $current = $('.main.current');
var $next = $current.nextAll('.main').eq(0);
$next.addClass('next');
```

```css
.next {
  background-color: #F00;
}
.main.current {
  background-color: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box main current">
    ... content main current ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>

  <div class="box main">
    ... content main ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>

  <div class="box main">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>

  <div class="box main">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
  <div class="box sub">
    ... content ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the next `.main` **is** a sibling of the `.main .current` element.

Instead of using `current.next('.main')`, use `current.siblings('.main')`. This will return a jQuery object that contains all the siblings of the current element that have the class `main`. Call `first` to get the first object.

To add a class to the next `.main` element, use this:

```
var current = $('.main.current');
current.siblings('.main').first().addClass('next');
```